# How to calculate diff between times in milliseconds

Tags: python

what i need to do is:

1. Check time at 1st point
2. Check time at 2nd point
3. Calculate if the difference between times
   is less then a timeout i have (0.5 seconds)

tried this :

```
>>> from time import time
>>> a=time
>>> b=time
>>> a-b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'builtin_function_or_method' and   builtin_function_or_method'
```

but im getting an error.

Please advice.

Comment: So, answer each part: 1) How to get current time (`python get current time precise`) and 2) How to compute difference between current time received (`python time difference`). Both of these should be easily-searchable.

Comment: Yes it was indeed easy , 
and i only realized it after BrtH's answer.
Did some research before asking :) Tho this time it wasnt enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually very easy to do:

```
from time import time

time_1 = time()
# do something
time_2 = time()
if time_2 - time_1 < .5:
    #do something
```

Comment: Well my only problem was i tried time1=time instead of time() :-\ thats why i thought i had it all wrong ..  Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

use the `time` module:

```
In [59]: import time

In [56]: s=time.time()

In [57]: t=time.time()

In [58]: t-s
Out[58]: 4.34810996055603
```

help on `time()`:

> time() -> floating point number
>
> Return the current time in seconds since the Epoch. Fractions of a
>   second may be present if the system clock provides them.

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime
first = datetime.now()
second = datetime.now()
result = first.microsecond-second.microsecond
if result > .5:
     #do whatever
```